# ie 6 sliding problems

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, slide

I have had this script written for me, for a sliding navigation (from right to left) with JQuery.

Works well in mac FF, safari, opera, PC ie 7 & 8, but is not working at all in ie6.

If anyone could shed any light as to why ie 6 isn't working it would be much appreciated.

It can be seen working here http://www.mitchellwood.co.uk/test/slide/navworking-alone.html

Comment: In IE7, the Sub Menus do not hide. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: Yeah, important to note that it doesn't work in IE7 either.

Answer (score 1):

Change navContent's css declaration to:

```
#navContent {
    position: relative;
    width: 348px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is a documented bug in IE6/7 that has been written about a bunch if you search for overflow: hidden ie7/ie6.

Have tested for continued compatibility in IE 6/7/8, FF3, Safari 4.

Answer (score 0):

In your css #navContent why have you two override one set to visible and another set to hidden ?

```
#navContent {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 348px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I had the same question, but I just tested it and it doesn't matter.